# Database not opening, after messing with datafiles

Tags: oracle, rman, sqlplus

I was exercising some database recovery exercises
First I had made a backup of my datafiles, then I moved them to another directory to test if I could recover them or not.
When I was recovering them on RMAN it was not successfully, so I restored the ones I moved to another directory, to see if it could work.
But I tried so much and now I'm getting this error

[image]
[image]

Comment: please do not post pictures of your output but post it as text. Format it as code: precede each line with  four blanks

Answer (score 1):

The creativity of some people breaking things never ceases to amaze me, I have never seen that error.

The error description clearly tells the solution, just make the file online (and recover it if needed):

```
$ oerr ora 1245
01245, 00000, "offline file %s will be lost if RESETLOGS is done"
// *Cause:  Attempting to do an OPEN RESETLOGS with a file that will be lost
//          because it is offline. The file was not taken offline with the
//          FOR DROP option.
// *Action: Either bring the file online and recover it, or take it offline
//          with the FOR DROP option.
```

Demo:

```
SQL> shu immediate
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1073741824 bytes
Fixed Size                  2932632 bytes
Variable Size             390070376 bytes
Database Buffers          675282944 bytes
Redo Buffers                5455872 bytes
Database mounted.
SQL> alter database datafile 1 offline;
alter database datafile 1 offline
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01145: offline immediate disallowed unless media recovery enabled


SQL> alter database archivelog;

Database altered.

SQL> alter database datafile 1 offline;

Database altered.
```

Here just pretend to make a recovery, then:

```
SQL> recover database until cancel;
ORA-01547: warning: RECOVER succeeded but OPEN RESETLOGS would get error below
ORA-01245: offline file 1 will be lost if RESETLOGS is done
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/oradata/ORCL2/system01.dbf'


SQL> alter database open resetlogs;
alter database open resetlogs
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01245: offline file 1 will be lost if RESETLOGS is done
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/oradata/ORCL2/system01.dbf'
```

Make it online and continue with the necessary steps.

```
SQL> alter database datafile 1 online;

Database altered.

SQL> alter database open resetlogs;

Database altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: Tried to do so, but it didn't work, I edited the post adding one more image with details